# Have bc not drop the trailing zeros while converting hex to binary

Tags: bash, bc

I have a bash script to convert hexadecimal to binary but I would like 8 bits regardless of the number supplied as the argument. For example hexadecimal `00` should be `00000000` not `0` or hexadecimal `01` should be `00000001`. This is the script but I couldn't figure out how to have `bc` do this. Is this possible or I should do it manually?

This is my script:

```
#!/bin/bash
for j in $@
do
    BIN=$(echo "obase=2; ibase=16; $j" | bc )
    echo $BIN
done
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know whether `bc` support such a behaviour but you could just replace

```
echo $BIN
```

with

```
printf "%08d\n" "$BIN"
```

Comment: Are the double quotation marks around `$BIN` necessary?

Comment: It prevents word splitting in case `BIN` contains some character in `IFS`. In such case `printf` would reuse the pattern for each splitted word and multiple numbers would be printed. With the quotes, the whole string would be used and an error message printed. Additionally, `printf` would exit with status 1 and one zero would be printed...I don't know how to prevent that...maybe assigning the result to a variable and print that only if `printf` succeeded.